# Angular 6 | Server side rendering: issue 'window not defined'

Tags: angular, angular6, server-side-rendering, angular-seo

I have updated my application from angular version 5 to latest. Here's detail:

```
  Angular CLI: 6.2.1
  Node: 8.12.0
  OS: win32 x64
  Angular: 6.1.6
```

Also I am using  [this: ng-toolkit-universal](https://medium.com/@maciejtreder/angular-server-side-rendering-with-ng-toolkit-universal-c08479ca688)
to achieve server side rendering. I am able to build application using command "*npm run build:prod*" , but facing following issue while running command: "n*pm run server*":

[image]

Can anyone please help or suggest some soution for the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you used the `window` Object in your Angular App? If you have, It's advisable to use `Renderer2` for doing DOM Manipulations instead of directly using the `window` or the `document` object.

Comment: Have you looked at the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48557931/server-side-rendering-angular-4-5-issue) OR [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48439557/angular-4-universal-window-is-not-defined)?

Comment: Hi @SiddAjmera, Thanks for reply! Yes, I am using window object but not using Renderer2. Let me try that.

Comment: That explains why you're getting this error. Angular Universal doesn't have access to the `window` or the `document` object as it runs on Server. That's why Angular Team recommends use of `Renderer2`

Comment: @SiddAjmera  Actually, i am new to this and trying my hands on it. I hope Renderer2 will resolve my problem. Do u know any good example/link for the same in angular 6?

Comment: Try this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/server-side-rendering-in-angular-2-with-angular-universal

Comment: Hi @Narm, thanks for reply. Checked these links and got to know about 'domino'. Do u know more about this in angular 6?

Comment: Hi @SiddAjmera, I have implemented `Renderer2` , but now facing this issue 

`{ Error: StaticInjectorError(AppServerModule)[NgClass -> ElementRef]:
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgClass -> ElementRef]:
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ElementRef!
    at NullInjector.module.exports.NullInjector.get (`
Could you please help?

Comment: We'd need to see your implementation to understand what's wrong.

Comment: @SiddAjmera oh, but it's a huge application and can't share. One more thing, now when i run`ng serve` its giving an error in browser console:
`Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppModule -> InjectionToken ng-toolkit-local-storage]` any idea about this?

Comment: Check if the suggestions in [**here**](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20101) work for you

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are done SSR with angular universal. Put following code in your server.ts after imports. Build and run.

```
const domino = require("domino");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const templateA = fs
  .readFileSync(path.join("dist/browser", "index.html"))
  .toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(templateA);
win.Object = Object;
win.Math = Math;

global["window"] = win;
global["document"] = win.document;
global["branch"] = null;
global["object"] = win.object;
global['HTMLElement'] = win.HTMLElement;
global['navigator'] = win.navigator;
global['localStorage'] = localStorage;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. I am using angular 14(same version of angular universal as well)